# Как вывести последнее записанное значение из таблицы?

Tags: django, django-orm

Есть форма вывода:

```
#   Название    Ситуация    Последнее значение  Ключ
1   Параметр    fthfhgfnc                       2229c9b7825e
```

Значения падают в свою таблицу связанную через:

```
class Parametr(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    parametr = models.FloatField(max_length=8)
    key = models.ForeignKey('Datchik', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Parametrs')

    def para(self):
        self.time = timezone.now()
        self.save()

class Datchik(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=36, default=uuid.uuid4)#PKключ датчика
    #Контрольное значение для валидации
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)#название датчика
    tip = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    projects = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Datchiks')#название проекта
    description1 = models.TextField()#Описание зеленое
    description2 = models.TextField()#Описание желтое
    description3 = models.TextField()#Описание красное
    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

Как отобразить в выводе последнее принятое значение параметра конкретного датчика?

Пробовал так:

```
{%for datchik in datchiks%}
            <hr>{{ datchik.id }}</hr>
            <hr>{{ datchik.title }}</hr>
                    {%for parametr in datchik.Parametrs.all%}
                        {{ parametr.parametr }}
                     {%endfor%}

            {%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Определяете `Parametr`. Например,

   parametr = Parametr.objects.get(id=1)
2. Определяете `Datchick` для этого `parametr`, используя `related_name`. Для получения последнего значения используете либо `first`, либо `last`, в зависимости от сортировки.

   datchick = parametr.Parametrs.last()
3. Передаёте значение в `context` в функции.

---

Либо же определяете аналогичным образом в шаблоне. Сначала определяете `parametr`, а затем `{{ parametr.Parametrs.last }}`

Comment: Стыдно-то как))) В переменных запутался, да, работает спасибо!